# A device to negate time dilation believability

Tags: science-fiction, space-travel, time-travel, faster-than-light

In this setting spacecraft are able to approach the speed of light and are equipped with a device to negate the time dilation, this allows things to go horribly wrong if this device fails plot wise.

Does this sound plausible/believable in a soft to medium sci-fi setting?

Edit: This is an effort at a simple and material way to handwave the effects of time dilation while still acknowledging it exist and leaving it open to manipulation and technological breakthrough. However I am not sure of the consequences in a universe where such a device exist.

Edit 2: Reworded the question, thankyou to Shawn for the realisation on time dilation vs FTL travel.

Comment: Since time dilation involves the fundamental structure of the  universe, then in a soft version, maybe. Medium to hard, no. But this is very much an opinion question and is likely to get closed as such.

Comment: Plausible/believable is more about the writer's ability to sell a work of fiction than it is a function of the facts of the world itself. A good story teller can get a receptive reader to believe all sorts of fantastic/implausible things.

Comment: I'd have to ask, why this particular maguffin? There are far and away plenty ways something could go horribly wrong during FTL travel without playing mental gymnastics with relativity...(Is that a pun or something? That should be a pun.).

Comment: @Gillgamesh This was indeed an effort at a simple and materialistic way to not have to worry about the effects of time dilation while still acknowledging it exist. But It turns my head to mush trying to think of how this would effect everything else, hence the question.

Comment: @Stargazer there are plenty of theoretical ways to travel ftl seen in scifi and physics, without time dilation.  Alcubierre warp drive. Wormholes, jump gate, teleportation are a few.

Comment: @Gillgamesh My bad I am indeed getting time dilation mixed up with the time travel paradoxes that occur from any faster then light travel breaking causality. Which is a whole other bag of worms.

Comment: First of all, any FTL travel is time travel. No exceptions. Second, there is no theory on what happens to time during FTL travel. Time dilation is only known for relativistic travel. So, just make up whatever you want. Nobody can say you're wrong.

Comment: Time dilation at 0.9 *c* is a factor of 2.3, perfectly tolerable. At 0.99 *c* is raises to a factor of 7.1 (while the duration of travel is only reduced by 10%), and at 0.99 *c* it balloons to a factor of 22.4 (while the duration of travel is only reduced by 11%). *On the other hand*, time dilation makes the duration of travel appear *shorter* for the travellers; so that from the point of view of the travellers you do not really want to negate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It's time dilation or time travel

Let's look at a particular scenario: A beam of light bouncing between two mirrors on a ship in space. On the ship, the distance between the mirrors is 4 metres, and so it takes 4 light metres for a single traversal. From some other ship, the ship is moving at a speed of 3 metres per traversal. From this other ship, the light takes 5 light metres for a traversal. This means that it must be the case that for every 5 light metres on the observer's ship, only 4 light metres can pass on the other

But, if we engage your time-dilation nullifier, then 4 light metres is 4 light metres, regardless of the ship. To maintain consistency between observers, this means that the light completes a traversal in the same time for both. Unfortunately, this entains the light cover 5 metres in 4 light metres: This is faster than light travel, and now causality is dead

## What does this device do anyway?

What exactly does it mean to not have time dilation? If you're not running by your own clock, which one are you running by? And why is that? There is no prefered frame in relativity, every particle has its own, equally good perspective from which the universe works perfectly and consisently. Hence, there's no way to even truly define what your device does, let alone what all the consequences might be

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, I have indeed realised it is quite a useless device, and would probably break the fabric of the universe. So I will forget that one.